# Cannot convert a valid UUID string to UUID using mapper.readValue

Tags: java, uuid, mapper

I have a valid UUID in string format

```
7a041f81-1214-41e5-bb58-9a46b2ca08d4
```

but when I user a `ObjectMapper` to convert it to a UUID I keep getting this error.

```
    UUID uuid = mapper.readValue("7a041f81-1214-41e5-bb58-9a46b2ca08d4",UUID.class);
```

error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
>       Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): Expected space separating root-level values
>        at [Source: (String)"7a041f81-1214-41e5-bb58-9a46b2ca08d4"; line: 1, column: 3]
>           at com.xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.Test.callTest(BmcEventListenerTest.java:22

how can I convert the string to UUID and why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON so why do you expect objectMapper will read it?

Comment: Why are you using a jackson ObjectMapper do convert a String to a UUID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Object mapper, you can do the following

```
UUID obj = UUID.fromString("7a041f81-1214-41e5-bb58-9a46b2ca08d4");
```

Demo: https://onecompiler.com/java/3v2sr8pk8

Comment: @Hummingbird because you are using classes that parse json without any json being involved

Comment: @f1sh ok so i'm curious would this format work?? `"{"uuid":7a041f81-1214-41e5-bb58-9a46b2ca08d4}"` ??

Comment: JSON doesn't have a UUID type - The JSON parser is seeing the leading '7' and assuming it can parse a number, then it encounters the 'a' and is forced to give up because it can't parse the string into a number anymore.

Comment: Your JSON needs to have quotes around the value part, so the UUID is initially read as a String.  Without it being a string, it is invalid JSON, as it is not a number or boolean , etc.

Comment: If you have to use the mapper only then you can do the following ```mapper.readValue("\"7a041f81-1214-41e5-bb58-9a46b2ca08d4\"", UUID.class);```  Please do accept the anser, if it solved your problem.